How can I make mixin type works in nested mixin functions?
This mixin is borrowed from https://github.com/1nVitr0/lib-ts-mixin-extended , I want write a mixin function also has mixins, for nested I mean
function createBarFields() {
  return <TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) => {
    class HasBarMixin extends mixin(Base, withFooFields) {
      bar?: string = 'bar';
    }

    return HasBarMixin;
  };
}

This will report
Type is not a constructor function type.(2507)

If I force the result like MixinReturnValue<T, M> & Constructor, the error is gone, but the result type missing the field foo, How can I make this right, is this possible ?
Playground
